# How to add a values (html select) to custom field?

Tags: extension

I am creating an extension. I created a custom group and custom field. The data and input field type is alphanumeric and select. I want to add multiple choice option into that custom field using an extension. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [managed](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_managed/) hook to create custom field on install

1. Create Option Group
   2.Create option values for option group
2. Create custom group
3. Create custom field.

There is another way of doing this i.e by creating xml file. A good example to refer would be https://github.com/compucorp/civihr/blob/master/hrcareer/xml/auto_install.xml

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: How to set values to the custom field using API?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for this hook:
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_fieldOptions/

It lets you set the values in the select dropdown on-the-fly.

Comment: How to add values for the custom field using API explorer v3? (support -> Developer ->API explorer v3).

Comment: I saw documentation but not understood. Please give some example.